# Magento 1.7.0.1 : After installing magento SUPEE 6788 patch iframe stop working in product description

Tags: magento-1.7, iframe

I have website with `magento 1.7.0.1` and i have recently installed magento security patch `SUPEE 6788` and all working fine but however iframe stop loading in product description. There are 3 iframe in product description and only 1st one is loaded.

`<iframe src="---" frameborder="0" width="590" height="332"></iframe>`

Can anyone face this type of issue?

Comment: It should not be related to the patch. Does these iframes load some external content or from inside Magento ? Can you see them in page source ?

Comment: Please share the URLs for these iframes if they are URLs within your Magento shop.

Answer (score 2):

It is not because of magento security patch but it is because of website is running on `https://` so i need to enter YouTube URL with `https://`.